# HTTP header - about the delimiter

Tags: http

Recently I read something about HTTP header format, I think I found some rule about it, but I cannot confirm it.

for example:

```
Some-Header:Foo;x=foo_attr,Bar;y=bar_attr\r\n
```

Foo and Bar are the list items of Some-Header, x is the attribute of Foo, y is the attribute of Bar, right?
If it is right, "," should be the delimiter of header items, and ";" should be the delimiter of the attributes of header item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, how a HTTP header should be parsed depends on the header. You can't really look at a header and make assumptions about the structural format, because the format differs on a per-header basis.

What can be said is that for almost all HTTP headers, the comma represents multiple values your example is identical to:

```
Some-Header:Foo;x=foo_attr
Some-Header:Bar;y=bar_attr
```

However, there are exceptions to this rule. You can't for example do the same thing with the `Set-Cookie` header. `Set-Cookie` is the only exception I can recall from the top of my head though. (there might be more).

But aside from that, it's basically up to you. If you're defining `Some-Headers` then you need to tell implementors how to parse it.

There currently an effort to come up a standard way to describe structures in headers. You can read the current draft here:

[draft-ietf-httpbis-header-structure](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-header-structure)